# Read instance of a combined datatype with Haskell

Tags: haskell, instance, ghc

I implemented these (simplified) datatypes in a Haskell program :

```
data Type  = ValA
           | Valb
           | ValC

data Prefix = PrefA
            | PrefB
            | PrefC
            | NoPref

data Combin = Combin Prefix Type

instance Show Type where
  show ValA = "typeA"
  show Valb = "O"
  show ValC = "mp"

instance Read Type where
  readsPrec  _ "typeA" = [(ValA,"")]
  readsPrec  _ "O"     = [(Valb,"")]
  readsPrec  _ "mp"    = [(ValC,"")]

instance Show Prefix where
  show PrefA = "a"
  show PrefB = "bm"
  show PrefC = "c"
  show NoPref = ""

instance Read Prefix where
  readsPrec  _ "a"  = [(PrefA,"")]
  readsPrec  _ "bm" = [(PrefB,"")]
  readsPrec  _ "c"  = [(PrefC,"")]
  readsPrec  _ ""   = [(NoPref,"")]

instance Show Combin where
  show (Combin pre typ) = show pre++show typ
```

With the instances, I'm able to `show` and `read` the types `Prefix` and `Type`. The `Combin` datatype is a concatenation of a `Prefix` and a `Type`.
Now, I would like to implement the read instance for the `Combin` datatype and I have no idea on how to do it.

I thought about deriving the Combin type, but it cause the output string of Combin PrefA ValC to be "Combin a mp". And it's not what I want. I want "amp" concatened together. Same thing for read

I thought about making pattern matching with the input string but the `Prefix` strings have differents length and may be void (`NoPref`).

**Have you ever implemented a such functionnality with read ? Do you know how to do it ?**

Comment: Why not just use `deriving (Read, Show)`?  That way you don't have to write any of those instances

Comment: Because deriving `Combin` cause the output string of `Combin PrefA ValC` to be "Combin a mp". And it's not what I want. I want "amp" concatened together. Same thing for read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `readsPrec` implementations are wrong, since they are supposed to accept valid prefixes of the input, not necessarily consume the whole input. Your `readsPrec` functions are not composable.

The key to the solution is to rewrite them so that they check if their input matches any of the names:

```
import Data.List (stripPrefix)

instance Read Type where
    readsPrec _ s | Just s' <- stripPrefix "typeA" s = [(ValA, s')]
                  | Just s' <- stripPrefix "O" s     = [(Valb, s')]
                  | Just s' <- stripPrefix "mp" s    = [(ValC, s')]
                  | otherwise = []
```

and similarly for `Prefix`:

```
instance Read Prefix where
    readsPrec _ s | Just s' <- stripPrefix "a" s  = [(PrefA, s')]
                  | Just s' <- stripPrefix "bm" s = [(PrefB, s')]
                  | Just s' <- stripPrefix "c" s  = [(PrefC, s')]
                  | otherwise = [(NoPref, s)]
```

Note the last branch of `readsPrec` for `Prefix`, which says that every string that doesn't begin with `"a"`, `"bm"` or `"c"` is to be parsed as `NoPref`. This only works for `Combin` because there's no `Type` which starts with any of the `Prefix` bits; otherwise, the parser for `Prefix` would need to be nondeterminstic, since a string like `"aXY"` could either correspond to a `Prefix` of `"a"` and a `Type` of `"XY"`, or a `Prefix` of `NoPref` and a `Type` of `"aXY"`. I went with the deterministically eager version here because I think it's going to be easier for you to understand how it works.

Once we have these two `Read` instances, writin ghte one for `Combin` is a straightforward matter of trying to read the whole string with `reads` for `Prefix`, and then trying to read each remainder as a `Type`:

```
instance Read Combin where
    readsPrec _ s = [(Combin pre typ, s'') | (pre, s') <- reads s, (typ, s'') <- reads s']
```

If you are familiar with `do` notation and the `[]` monad, you can rewrite this as

```
instance Read Combin where
    readsPrec _ s = do
        (pre, s) <- reads s
        (typ, s) <- reads s
        return (Combin pre typ, s)
```